# I want to login user after registration with laravel with redis not mysql .How can i do that?

Tags: laravel, redis

In [LController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXSlg.png) i have set the values for the key user,  in function `Regiterinsert` and also got the values  by  using `$response = $redis->get('user');` but if i want to check the credentials for login what can i do.
`Auth::attempt($credentials)` doesn't work .
below is my code of controller

```
 public function Regiterinsert(Request $resuest){
    $input = Input::all();
    // echo("<pre>");print_r($input);echo("</pre>");
    $redis = Redis::connection();
    $views = $redis->set('user', json_encode(
                                        array(
                                            'firstname' => $input['firstname'],
                                            'lastname' => $input['lastname'],
                                            'email'=>$input['email'], 
                                            'password' => $input['password'],
                                            'token' => $input['_token']
                                          )
                                   )
                        );
    $response = $redis->get('user');
    $response = json_decode($response,true);
    echo("<pre>");print_r($views);echo("</pre>");
    echo("<pre>");print_r($response);echo("</pre>");

    $credentials = [
        "email" => $response['email'],
        "password" => $response['password']
    ];

}
```

Comment: You can start by asking the right question (I mean formatted properly). Just put the code itself here not by picture but by text so we can copy and work with it.

Comment: please help, I am stuck since 2 days, not able to understand how can I make this user login the moment he registers.

Comment: Instead of using `// echo("<pre>");print_r($input);echo("</pre>");` you can use `dd($input)` or `dump($input)`. The rest you must figure out on your own, sorry.

Comment: that I did just for checking my response, my issue is that how can I authenticate user for login with redis

Comment: do you get anything in $response?

Comment: yes i get 'firstname' => $input['firstname'],
                                            'lastname' => $input['lastname'],
                                            'email'=>$input['email'], 
                                            'password' => $input['password'],
                                            'token' => $input['_token']